# Check to see if at the end of for/in loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a for/in loop that I would like to know if I'm at the end of. I'm not entirely sure how this would work?

**My code is:**

```
for (const key in posts.val()) {
    if(posts.val()[key][postId] != undefined) {
        found = true;
        //do something
    } else {
         // if at end && found !== true
      }
 }
```

Any idea how I would know if I'm at the end of the for/in loop?

Thank you!

Comment: Last as in the enumeration order of keys for object or is there a specific `last` key?

Comment: No there is no `last` key, just if we hit the bottom of the for loop and `found` is still false

Comment: Why not check outside the `for` loop?

Comment: Using `posts.val()` seems like it is not very efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality for something like that. Assuming the properties don't get mutated when `.val()` is called, you *could* call `.val()` initially to get the object, count up the number of keys (including inherited keys) with `for..in`, and then use `for..in` *again* to iterate and be able to test how close you are to the end of the loop:

```
const val = posts.val();
let totalKeyCount = 0;
for (const _ in posts.val()) {
  totalKeyCount++;
}
let keyIndex = 0;
for (const key in posts.val()) {
  keyIndex++;
  if(val[key][postId] != undefined) {
    found = true;
    //do something
  } else {
    if (keyIndex === totalKeyCount) {
      console.log('last iteration');
    }
  }
}
```

But, if you *don't* depend on *inherited* keys, it would be better to use `Object.keys`, which returns an *array*, and upon which array methods can be used.

Assuming you're trying to find a particular value in the object (and on the object itself), you can use `.find` on `Object.values` instead:

```
const foundPost = Object.values(posts.val()).find(item => item[postId] !== undefined);
// if an item[postId], if it exists, will be truthy, simplify to `item => item[postId]`
if (foundPost) {
  // do something with the found post
} else {
  // all iterations have been completed, and nothing was found
}
```

Also note that the order of properties iterated on in a `for..in` loop is *not* entirely reliable. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties) says:

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order (see the delete operator for more on why one cannot depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a cross-browser setting).

Answer (score 1):

There's no real notion of end of an object unless you mean the last key to iterate. You can get the object's keys, iterate, and check the index against keys.length-1:

```
let obj = posts.val();

Object.keys(obj).forEach((k, i, keys) => {
    if(obj[k][postId] !== undefined) {
        let found = true;
        //do something
    } else {
        let atEnd = (i === keys.length-1);
        // if at end && found !== true
    }
});
```

Typically, finding something looks like this:

```
function isFound(obj, cmpFn) {
    let found = false;
    for (let k in obj) {
        if (cmpFn(obj[k]) === true) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Or:

```
function isFound(obj, cmpFn) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
                 .some(k => cmpFn(obj[k]));
}
```

You should have both keys somewhere, so you can avoid iteration entirely:

```
let isFound = (id_b in obj[id_a]);
```

The above works if you don't store empty entries in the table, which is usually desirable.

I'd also recommend using `!==` over `!=` to avoid coercion and ambiguity.